# Cannot install mono older version

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, installation, mono

I am trying to install mono-devel package of version 4.4.2. OS: Ubuntu 16.04.
Current stable version of Mono is 5.0.0.100. So, if I am installing with instructions, taken from [official mono download page](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin), Mono 5.0.0 is installed. That's is how official mono download page says:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```

It works. But it installs mono 5.0.0 as expected.

To install mono 4.4.2 I change command to (due to "accessing older mono released guide" - http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#accessing-older-releases):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu xenial/snapshots/4.4.2 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```

It fails: cannot locate mono distribution files.

I have tried to find this distributions manually here:

```
http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists/xenial/snapshots/
```

But I found only the latest mono distribution files (version 5.0.0).

Is there any possibility to install Mono 4.4.2 for now? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: They have used a new infrastructure to host Mono 5.0 bits, so I think maybe they have no plan for you to install previous releases. Why do you need those old bits then?

Comment: @LexLi I have reference to external library, which does not work under Mono 5.0

Comment: Interesting. Mono 5.0 is more compatible to .NET Framework, so which library does not work on it?

Comment: @LexLi It is [GrEmit](https://github.com/skbkontur/gremit).